# Aligning text in PHP

Tags: php, html

I created a description("specs") in my table in my database. and put in on my php file.

```
 <h5><?php echo $row["specs"];?></h5>
```

How can I align my text like these:

```
Bold: Details

Bold: Details

Bold: Details

Bold: Details

Bold: Details
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Please show effort and HTML you tried. You can use CSS and possibly tables depending on your data

Comment: Be more specific. Please show more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the html table element will be most suitable for this:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["the field in Bold"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Details field"];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

In CSS:

```
table td:first-child{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

It works like that. In you question the elements are aligned like that:

```css
table td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>bold:</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bold:</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bold:</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bold:</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where should i put the CSS file in my htdocs folder? I think it is not reading the CSS file

Comment: Typically CSS files are in css folder and are linked from head of the html file.  <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></head>

Comment: I got it, the bold style is working but it still doesnt align:
It goes like these: Bold: Bold: Bold: instead of
Vertically Alligned

Comment: I have the bold and description in my table in database already. I just need it to align in my php file.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
  foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo "\n<h5>" . $row["specs"] . "</h5>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\cpu1.php on line 318

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\cpu1.php on line 318

Comment: You must loop database results somehow. I have guessed rows were stored in $rows variable. How do you code the loop?